# how properly to align 3 divs as circles in one line?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Trying to make a legend like block and struggling with alignment, need some advice-correction:

```css
.footertext {
  display: flex;                  /* establish flex container */
  flex-direction: row;            /* default value; can be omitted */
  flex-wrap: nowrap;              /* default value; can be omitted */
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 260px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}

.circlemarker {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 78px;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10),
              -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.circlemarker p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
}

#accactive {
  background: #1698D1;
}
#accdisabled {
  background: #979797;
}
#accprivileged {
  background: #FF9563;
}
```

```html
<div class="footertext">
  <div>
    <div class="circlemarker" id="accactive" ><p>Active</p></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="circlemarker" id="accdisabled"><p>Disabled</p></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="circlemarker" id="accprivileged"><p>Privileged</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so its looks almost ok, because I add

```
margin-right: 78px;
```

but such kind of "hardcoded" value and if size will change it will not fit well, so how I can change css so its looks same but be independent from margin? Also it seems not centred vertically.
p.S.
Yellow background has been added just to show boundaries of parent

Comment: Use `.footertext { align-items: center; }`

Comment: Your HTML has too many `<div>` elements which will make it harder to maintain - why not use `<ul>` or `<dl>` instead?

Comment: dont work well, as text is outside of div :(

Comment: Remove the `height` and `width` on `.circlemarker` and instead use the `::before` pseudo-element for the circle.

Comment: not sure i got you, i may want to change they size and not sure where to put ::before

Comment: Use `.circlemarker::before { display: inline-block; width: 16px; height: 16px; content: ''; background-color: red; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.footertext {
  width: 260px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.wrapper{
    display: flex;                  /* establish flex container */
  flex-direction: row;            /* default value; can be omitted */
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.circlemarker-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.circlemarker {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10),
              -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.circlemarker p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
}

#accactive {
  background: #1698D1;
}
#accdisabled {
  background: #979797;
}
#accprivileged {
  background: #FF9563;
}
```

```html
<div class="footertext">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="circlemarker-wrapper">
      <div class="circlemarker" id="accactive" ></div>
      Active
    </div>
 
   <div  class="circlemarker-wrapper">
        <div class="circlemarker" id="accdisabled"></div>
        Disabled
   </div>
   <div class="circlemarker-wrapper">
    <div class="circlemarker" id="accprivileged"></div>
    Privileged
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this.

Comment: thanks almost - how I can add some space between bubbles and text without destroying alignment?

Comment: I have edited the file. Check now if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is "p" is outer the box model of "div class="circlemarker".
Hope this my idea have solved your problem by delete tag "p" and the circle move to div:before

```css
.footertext {
  display: flex;                  /* establish flex container */
  flex-direction: row;            /* default value; can be omitted */
  flex-wrap: nowrap;              /* default value; can be omitted */
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 260px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.circlemarker:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10),
              -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.circlemarker {
  position:relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
}

#accactive:before {
  background: #1698D1;
}
#accdisabled:before {
  background: #979797;
}
#accprivileged:before {
  background: #FF9563;
}
```

```html
<div class="footertext">
  <div>
    <div class="circlemarker" id="accactive" >Active</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="circlemarker" id="accdisabled">Disabled</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="circlemarker" id="accprivileged">Privileged</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the text outside the circlemarker to get the width of the flex items correct.
2. Make the footertext flex items be flexboxes themselves to get vertical centering.

```css
.footertext {
  display: flex;                  /* establish flex container */
  flex-direction: row;            /* default value; can be omitted */
  flex-wrap: nowrap;              /* default value; can be omitted */
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 260px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}

.footertext > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


.circlemarker {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10),
              -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
}

#accactive {
  background: #1698D1;
}
#accdisabled {
  background: #979797;
}
#accprivileged {
  background: #FF9563;
}
```

```html
<div class="footertext">
  <div>
    <div class="circlemarker" id="accactive"></div><span>Active</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="circlemarker" id="accdisabled"></div><span>Disabled</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="circlemarker" id="accprivileged"></div><span>Privileged</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should update the indentation and formatting of the HTML to reflect the fact that the `<span>` elements are no-longer children of `<div class="circlemarker">` (i.e. the `<span>` elements should be on their own line).